# Prove that space of continuous functions from R is normal

Tags: general-topology

I've been trying really hard to solve this problem:

*Let $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions with continuous derivatives.
Show that $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is normal.*

**Def:**
A topological space X is called **normal** if it is Hausdorff and any two closed disjoint subsets can be seperated topologically.

**Def:**
A topological space (X,T) is **Hausdorff** if for any x,y in X, there are neighbourhood V of x and W of y, such that that V and W don't intersect.

When I start working with neighbourhoods, I'm pretty sure I need to know how the topology T is defined. This topology isn't defined in the question, and I can't think of a way to continue.

So the main question are which topology is used, or if this is irrelevant and if so, why?

I've researched quite a lot, but in vain. I hope someone here can help me!

Comment: Your definition of *normal* is not the usual one. Yours implies that all normal spaces are discrete.The standard one is that "any two *closed* disjoint subsets can be seperated topologically".

Comment: Anyway, what is the topology you define on $C^1(\Bbb R )$?

Comment: How is the topology defined on $C^1(\mathbb{R})$? You cannot go on without that information.

Comment: Yea, you're right I edited it now.
That's my problem, there's no topology defined in the question, so I thought maybe it was supposed to be obvious and I just didn't know...

Comment: I don’t understand, how one can try really hard to deal with a topological space without a topology. :-) Without the topology a question about its normality is senseless, so I vote to close it. In my professional topologist opinion, this should be the only right answer to a person who give you the question.